# Only 1/4 of image will upload to webapi

Tags: post, image-processing, asp.net-web-api, xamarin

Im currently trying to upload an image from an android device using Xamarin forms.
All the entries to the database work fine and the image does upload but only about 1/4 of the image

[image: file that uploaded]

I've been using the same code to upload an image when i take a photo with the camera.

This problem occurs when i select a image from the phone gallery. I then check that the whole is was being selected by displaying it on the phone screen which worked fine.

The image starts to upload then about 3 seconds in it stop to upload. The error message i get back is Internal Server Error" so then i updated the web.config on my webapi to.

```
<system.web.extensions>
<scripting>
  <webServices>
    <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483644"/>
  </webServices>
</scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
```

and also

```
maxRequestLength="50000"
```

but didn't solve my problem

here is the code for which i choose an image and upload

```
 private async void SaveNewLogo(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Stream stream = new MemoryStream(mysfile);
        var FixedFileName = DateTime.Now.Millisecond + "BusinessLogo_" + BusinessID + ".jpg";
        try
        {
            StreamContent scontent = new StreamContent(stream);
            scontent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
            {
                FileName = FixedFileName,
                Name = "image"
            };
            scontent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpg");
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var multi = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            multi.Add(scontent);
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://mywebapi.azurewebsites.net/");
            var result = client.PostAsync("api/Business/UpdateBusinessLogo/" + BusinessID, multi).Result;
            await DisplayAlert("Err", result.ToString(), "OK");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ExceptionUtility.LogException(ex, "An Error Occured at : SaveNewLogo MOBILE ");
            ExceptionUtility.NotifySystemOps(ex);
        }
    }
```

and to recieve the data from my webapi

```
    <Route("api/Business/UpdateBusinessLogo/{businessId}")> _
   <HttpPost>
   <HttpGet>
    Function UpdateBusinessLogo(businessId As Integer)
        Try
            Dim root As String = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Files/BusinessLogos/Medium")
            Dim provider = New CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root)
            Dim task = Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider) _
            .ContinueWith(Of HttpResponseMessage)(Function(t)
                                                      If t.IsFaulted OrElse t.IsCanceled Then
                                                          Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, t.Exception)
                                                      End If
                                                      For Each uploadedFile As MultipartFileData In provider.FileData
                                                      Next
                                                      Return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK)
                                                  End Function)
            Dim path As String = provider.FileData(0).LocalFileName
            Dim pos As Integer = path.LastIndexOf("\") + 1
            Dim GeneratedFileName As String = path.Substring(pos, path.Length - pos)
            Dim GetBusiness = db.Businesses.SingleOrDefault(Function(x) x.ID = businessId)
            GetBusiness.BusinessLogoURL = "http://mywebapi.azurewebsites.net/Files/BusinessLogos/Medium/" & GeneratedFileName
            GetBusiness.BusinessLogoImageFile = GeneratedFileName
            db.SaveChanges()
            Return task
        Catch ex As Exception
            ExceptionUtility.LogException(ex, "An Error Occured at : UpdateBusinessLogo : ")
            ExceptionUtility.NotifySystemOps(ex)
            Return "False"
        End Try
    End Function
```

everything seems to work, all my data in the db gets save fine. Just the image when i view the file on the filesystem there is only a portion of the image.

just incase it may help il include my resizing code for the android.

```
  public byte[] ResizeTheImage(byte[] imageData, float width, float height)
    {
        // Load the bitmap
        Bitmap originalImage = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageData, 0, imageData.Length);
        Bitmap resizedImage = Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(originalImage, (int)width, (int)height, false);

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            resizedImage.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, ms);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

again if i take a picture with the camera it works fine but selecting from the gallery the error happens

EDIT

When posting to the webapi using fidder i get this error message

The method 'UpdateBusinessLogo' on type 'BusinessesController' returned a Task instance even though it is not an asynchronous method

Answer (score 0):

Fixed now, all was need was to make the webapi function a Async function.. opps!!